# C# ListView HitTest can only select items in first column

Tags: c#, .net, listview

I am using the following code to figure out which cell is clicked

```
    private void listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var info = listView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        var row = info.Item.Index;
        var col = info.Item.SubItems.IndexOf(info.SubItem);
        var value = info.Item.SubItems[col].Text;
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("R{0}:C{1} val '{2}'", row, col, value));

    }
```

However it only works for items in the first column, and I can not click cells in the second or third columns. I want to be able to click on the third column, and have it open the colorpicker.

Comment: You need to explain what is not working better.  The code should test that `info` is not null which will happen if they click in a non-row area, but otherwise should work.